# Jenkins: Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

*I am able to archive ios project using below commands*

`cordova build ios --device --debug`

*and*

`cordova build ios --device --release`

But when i try to do same from **`jenkins`** i am getting below error.

```
11:08:01 SecKey API returned: -25308, (null)/Users/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GRC_Pulse-ebufuetkmalmfxbiegclmzuryhrm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/GRC Pulse/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/GRC Pulse.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
11:08:01 Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
11:08:01 
11:08:01 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
11:08:01 
11:08:01 
11:08:01 The following build commands failed:
11:08:01    CodeSign /Users/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GRC_Pulse-ebufuetkmalmfxbiegclmzuryhrm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/GRC\ Pulse/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/GRC\ Pulse.app
11:08:01 (1 failure)
11:08:01 Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/Jenkins/projects/grc-pulse-hybrid-custom/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,GRC Pulse.xcworkspace,-scheme,GRC Pulse,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,GRC Pulse.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Jenkins/projects/grc-pulse-hybrid-custom/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/Jenkins/projects/grc-pulse-hybrid-custom/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Answer (score 6):

You should unlock your keychain before running the command when using ssh (connection from the master to a slave)

security unlock-keychain -p "" ${keychain}

Take a look on this [link](http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site/howto/HandlingKeychainsInMasterSlaveEnvironment.html) for more details

Comment: Really helped! And thanks for given that link to us.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with Xcode 8.3:

```
unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

And

```
security unlock-keychain -p "mypass" ${mykeychain}
```

solved it, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to chip in as well as I had to try a few more things than the ones mentioned here: the problem (for me) was that keychain doesn't like SSH sessions. I had to execute these in my session to fix it:

```
security unlock-keychain -p MY_PASS ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k MY_PASS ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-keychain-settings ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

I've also removed my current certificates system/account certificates by removing my account from XCode (I use fastlane to do building) but I suspect that this shouldn't have impacted it.

This is now my third post about this or so but I sure hope it is going to help to save 8h of work for somebody...